# Opencv: Is there a standard/proper way to return a matrx vs a return argument

Tags: c++, opencv

As I understand it, it's dangerous to return a Mat because the call to such a function might be a temporary variable (in an expression) and so the data ptr of the Mat that was created in the function would be released before the temporary expression that uses it is evaluated.

so, as I understand it, the code below is a problem because function M "owns" M , on it's stack, and when it is returned a shallow copy of M is returned but M's data pointer is released.  So, A=fred()+fred() should crash because the addition operator is working fred's temporary returns that  have invalid memory pointers. (right?)

```
Mat fred() {
 Mat M=Mat::zeros(5,5,CV_32F);
 return(M);
}

Mat A = fred() + fred();
```

As I understand it, MatExpr was made to deal with this.  In fact, from another post, here is the implementation of the "expression form" of the transpose function:

```
MatExpr MatExpr::t() const
{
  MatExpr e;
  op->transpose(*this, e);
  return e;
}
```

**So, is this, t(),  a general (standard/proper) method for how to make an expression form of any non expression function that has a Mat "return" argument (like transpose above)?**
Is it as simple as just create a MatExpr, vs a Mat, stack variable and call the non expression from with that in place of a Mat?

Note that the transpose function has its return arg as type OutputArray not Mat.  I admit I don't understand what exactly the difference between the two is; when to use one vs the other.   I tend to write functions were the return argument is a Mat alias (e.g. Mat &Dest).  **Can I call such with a Mat argument or does that only work with I had used OutputArray?** (e.g. if opencvs transpose 2nd arg with Mat & vs OutputArray would the function t() as defined above still work?)

**EDIT**

I hadn't noticed the op in op->transpose.  How about this:

Given a function with a "return" argument

```
void f(<input args>, Mat &OutputMatrix)
{
     .... // OutputMatrix = whatever.
}
```

Create an actual equivalent return form of it by:

```
MatExpr f(<input args>) 
{
    Mat Out;
    f(<input args>,Out);
    return(MatExpr(Out)); // is this generally OK for an expression using f?
}
```

I see that OpenCV codes uses OutputArray vs Mat & but I don't understand why etc.

Comment: There is probably a duplicate that explains this well, but both of your code samples are safe.  Neither one accesses a variable after it is destroyed.

Comment: OpenCV uses reference counters for `Mat` objects. When you return a `Mat` object from a function, the copy constructor is called but just the header is copied, the `data` pointer will be the same. So as long as there's an object pointing to the `data` pointer, it will not be destroyed.

Comment: Read more [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html).

Comment: @zindarod is right, there is typically nothing unsafe to return a cv::Mat that was created in the function.